# TS2362 and TS2345 error when subtracting a sessionStorage variable by 1

Tags: angular

I am working on MEAN stack development. I am facing two issues with my code.

> 1. error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
> 2. error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

**Code:**

```
var overNumber = sessionStorage.getItem("overNumber");
      var liactive = parseInt(overNumber - 1);
```

I am reading sessionStorage variable which is a string and converting it to integer to substract 1. 
but I am facing above errors on line number 2 when I am trying to perform operation.

I am new to typescript as well as angular 2.

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert overNumber to int and then subtract 1 from it.

```
 var liactive = parseInt(overNumber) - 1;
```